# AngularJS load font-face on demand

Tags: html, css, angularjs, font-face

I'm new to AngularJS. I have a web service which returns a list of cdn links for fonts. I want to use it and show some text using the fonts in run time. My client application is written in angularJS. How can I achieve this? Please help. This is what I have tried so far. How can I inject font faces on demand?

app.js (data returned by web service is shown as a list here.)

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', [] );

app.controller('appController', function($scope) {

    $scope.fonts = [
    {
        "family": "Abhaya Libre",
        "url": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mooniak/abhaya-libre-font/gh-pages/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Regular.otf"
    },
    {
        "family": "Gemunu Libre",
        "url": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mooniak/gemunu-libre-font/gh-pages/tests/fonts/GemunuLibre-Regular.otf"
    },
  ];

});
```

app.html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

  <p ng-repeat="font in fonts">

    <span style="@font-face {font-family:{{font.family}}; src: url({{font.url}});}">
      {{font.family}}
    </span>

  </p>

</div>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/lpsandaruwan/rpffoo06/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution, in the style you are not putting font-family:{{font.family}};
http://pastebin.com/WmBv5XDB